# Flutter How to convert Object of Object to List

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make a list of prices that I got from my API.

```
{
  product: {
     items: {
        price1: {}
        price2: {}
        price3: {}
     }
  }
}
 var productPrices = response.data
```

I have tried this one to get the prices but I would like a help to convert it to a List so I can map it to my widget, what I get in the list of Items is _JsonMap.

```
  productPrices.forEach((key, value) {
    print(key);
    final Map listofItems = Map.from(value);
    print(listofItems);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, [serialization](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json) is recommended, but if you want, you can quickly access the products as follows.

```
(jsonDecode(data)['product']['items'] as Map).values.toList()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing .items

Try:

```
productPrices.items.forEach((key, value) {
    print(key);
    final Map listofItems = Map.from(value);
    print(listofItems);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's better to create a class for product or which model you need. You can use this site to generate model from json. https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

After then you can use fromJson() method to generate object from json.